# How to remove Manifest internal service error

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have declared my Service inside my Voice Activity's `Voice.java` that

```
    public class Voice extends AppCompatActivity implements RecognitionListener {
            @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             startService(new Intent(Voice.this,task.class));
             }

            class task extends Service{
                 @Override
                 public void onCreate() {
                 //background code here
                  }
              
                   @Override
                  public void onDestroy() {
                    super.onDestroy();
                  }

                  @Nullable
                  @Override
                  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                    return null;
                  }
            }
```

and my manifest showing
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c71a3.png)

Instantiatable attribute missing

Comment: make task class public.

Comment: It is recommended to create a separate file for class task.

Comment: Please include the actual error rather than linking to an image file

Comment: Sir actual error is its 'missing instantiable attribute'